# XML to node in Drupal 6

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, feeds

I am using the Services module, through which I have created XML.

But i want to import this XML data into another drupal website. It contains images too.

I also installed feeds module but don't have idea how to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an XML parser module that interacts with node inserts, similar to feeds xml I would assume. This should allow you to insert the data into your db.

Comment: i already install this but hw to use this.

Comment: I would suggest you begin with reading this manual and checking out [this module](http://drupal.org/node/871384).